# How to turn a json array into rows in postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I am trying to convert this result where I have a JSON type column, which comes from a sql query

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "columns": {
        "jseq": 1,
        "Nombre": "0000956_LANZADOR",
        "rutaEsquema": "AXIS",
        "TipoDeComponente": "SQL",
        "value": 0,
        "detalleDelComponente": "Solución incidente 956"
      }
    },
    {
      "columns": {
        "jseq": 2,
        "Nombre": "0000956_02_Borrar_Mandatos.sql",
        "rutaEsquema": "AXIS",
        "TipoDeComponente": "SQL",
        "value": 1,
        "detalleDelComponente": "Brecha 67"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

to this

```
Nombre                     | rutaEsquema | TipoDeComponente | detalleDelComponente
---------------------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------------
0000956_LANZADOR           | AXIS        | SQL              | Solución incidente 956
0000956_02_Borrar_Mandatos | AXIS        | SQL              | Brecha 67
```

I am using Postgresql

Comment: Did you have a look at the JSON functions in Postgres?

Comment: "*which comes from a sql query*" - can you modify that query? If yes, please post it - sounds pretty unnecessary to create a JSON only to destructure it again.

Comment: The JSON that is returned from the query comes from a field that is generated by a Jira plugin whose result always comes in JSON format, it was not that I returned it JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json_to_record` and `json_to_recordset` from the [JSON processing functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) do exactly this. In your case:

```
SELECT cols.*
FROM json_to_recordset(yourJsonValue -> 'rows') AS rows(columns JSON),
     json_to_record(columns) AS cols(
       "Nombre" TEXT,
       "rutaEsquema" TEXT,
       "TipoDeComponente" TEXT,
       "detalleDelComponente" TEXT)
```

[online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=fc9efed9d5280853427aaa74258e3061)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT r."Nombre",
       r."rutaEsquema",
       r."TipoDeComponente",
       r."detalleDelComponente"
FROM jsonb_to_recordset(/* your JSONB value */ -> 'rows') AS q(columns jsonb)
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL
      jsonb_to_record(columns)
         AS r(jseq bigint,
              "Nombre" text,
              "rutaEsquema" text,
              "TipoDeComponente" text,
              value bigint,
              "detalleDelComponente" text
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using `json_each` function to expand the outermost JSON object into a set of key/value pairs, and then extract array elements by using `json_array_elements` :

```
select elm->>'Nombre' as Nombre,
       elm->>'rutaEsquema' as rutaEsquema,
       elm->>'TipoDeComponente' as TipoDeComponente,
       elm->>'detalleDelComponente' as detalleDelComponente
  from
  (
   select elms -> 'columns' as elm 
     from(
          select json_array_elements(js.value) as elms
            from tab,
                 json_each(js_col) as js
         ) q1
  ) q2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=8d0af3221e46ee212f30fcb50a9afcd8)</kbd>

Comment: You can simplify that nested query to `select json_array_elements(js_col -> 'rows') -> 'columns' as elm from tab`

Answer (score 0):

Find the simplified JSON query, for nested JSON object. This query simplified for clarification and better understanding.

#### Query

---

```
SELECT id, name FROM json_to_recordset('{
    "rows": [{
        "columns": {"id": 1, "name": "Chorke"}
    }, {
        "columns": {"id": 2, "name": "Academia"}
    }, {
        "columns": {"id": 3, "name": "Inc."}
    }]
}'::json -> 'rows') as list(columns json),
json_to_record(columns) AS concern(id int, name text);
```

#### Results

---

```
 id |   name   
----+----------
  1 | Chorke
  2 | Academia
  3 | Inc.
(3 rows)
```